# Java - Take HTML input type of file into java file object

Tags: java, html, file, input

I have an html input of type file (user browses to folder, selects file they want, and hit's ok). This is done using HTML. I want to take the file they select and put it into a java File object so that I can then mess with it.

Thanks

Edit: Not looking to upload the file, just need the file object that is the file they selected from the HTML input.

Comment: You have to give more information; although conventionally you would grab the selected file path (which depends on what you're using) and then create the File object: File file = new File("file.html");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is simply impossible, for many reasons. The two most obvious ones:

1. A `java.io.File` object represents a file on disk. It cannot represent a file in a zip, and it cannot represent a file on a completely different system
2. The browser will simply not send this information to you. When you select file, say, `/my/local/machine/foo.txt` in a file input field in HTML, all either the javascript or the server gets if the form is submitted is just `foo.txt`. Giving the full path would be a security leak which is why browsers are *never* going to give you that full path.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Makes sense. I'm creating a spring boot application. The user goes to our site, browses to a file of their choice, and then selects from a drop down where they want it to go and hit submit. I have java code that SFTPs the file perfectly. But i'm having issues getting the file so I can work with it. Do you suggest having it upload to our server so then I can play with it? I'm not worried about security because it's internal only, but I understand that may not matter. Thanks again @rzwitserloot